# flutter Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

### When i run App in IOS simulator, am getting this error Requested but did not find extension point with identifier com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore:pensive:
ERROR LOG

### xcodebuild[5612:51677] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
xcodebuild[5612:51677] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
Xcode's output:
↳
Writing result bundle at path:
/var/folders/_g/37p3zrmd2lbcvrsdpc74h7z80000gq/T/flutter_tools.rE1S6z/flutter_ios_build_temp_dird2sk6D/temporary_xcresult_bundle
: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
Failed to package /Users/infosys/mydrive/office-projects/myproject.
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
note: Using new build system
note: Planning
note: Build preparation complete
note: Building targets in dependency order

I tyied all solution flutter pub get,flutter clean ,deleting pod.lock file and yaml.lock file and derived data in xcode everyting,i dont know how to solve this issue.i already spend two weeks to find solution for this.no progress,plze help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Please do these steps

1. Delete Podfile.lock
2. delete .symlinks folder
3. delete pods folder
4. Delete XCWorkspace file
5. Make sure platform version in Pods file is uncommented and set it to 11.0
6. Navigate to iOS folder in terminal and run pod install
7. Open the xcworkspace in Xcode and select product -> clean build folder
8. if you notice any warnings please resolve them
9. Run the project from Xcode once and all subsequent builds should work from your IDE

Answer (score 0):

I fixed using this solution,this worked for me

1.added this packege **flutter_math_fork: any** in pubspec.yaml
2.delete pubspec.lock file and pod.lock file
3.do  flutter pub cache repair
4.do flutter pub get
5.do flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
6.do flutter clean
7.flutter pub get
8.pod install

thats all it will run

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was with the localisation wrongly done in Xcode. I had to add `Localizable.strings` to translate incoming push notifications send from my `Node.js` server, and I had the various languages `.lproj` folders both in iOS folder (which is correct) and in Runner folder (wrong).
So I deleted the `Localizable.strings`file, all the `.lproj` from both folders and the added languages from Xcode. I started fresh by creating the`Localizable.string` file at project `Runner` folder lever, re added the languages selecting only the `Localizable.strings` file and leaving unchecked both `Main.storyboard` and `Launch.storyboard` checkboxes. That creates only the `Localizable.strings` file in every language `.lproj` folder at iOS folder level. Now it all works as expected.
Hope this help other in the same hole.
Cheers